# Generate a column based on other column value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe :

```
Date_1      Date_2     is_B weight_1
01/09/2019  02/08/2019  1   254
01/09/2019  02/08/2019  1   320
01/09/2019  04/08/2019  1   244
01/09/2019  04/08/2019  1   247
01/09/2019  14/08/2019  0   343
01/09/2019  14/08/2019  1   161
01/09/2019  14/08/2019  1   386
01/09/2019  15/08/2019  1   465
01/09/2019  15/08/2019  1   133
01/09/2019  15/08/2019  1   310
01/09/2019  15/08/2019  1   155
```

I want to generate a column new_weight such that for each date_1, the value for new_weight is 5000 - weight_1 where the is_B value is 1. if is_B = 0 then we copy the older value of new_weight into new_weight.

I know for calculating new_weight, we can do :

```
df = 5000 - df.groupby('date_1')['weight_1'].cumsum()
```

But I am not sure how to apply the condition for is_b in the code.

Can anyone suggest a pandas or numpy way of doing the same?

**EDIT**

Expected Output

```
Date_1      Date_2     is_B weight_1  new_weight
01/09/2019  02/08/2019  1   254       5000-254
01/09/2019  02/08/2019  1   320       5000-254-320 
01/09/2019  04/08/2019  1   244       5000-254-320-244
01/09/2019  04/08/2019  1   247       5000-254-320-244-247
01/09/2019  14/08/2019  0   343       5000-254-320-244-247(we won't subtract 343 as isBooked = 0)
01/09/2019  14/08/2019  1   161       .
01/09/2019  14/08/2019  1   386       . 
01/09/2019  15/08/2019  1   465       . 
01/09/2019  15/08/2019  1   133       .
01/09/2019  15/08/2019  1   310       .
01/09/2019  15/08/2019  1   155       .
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @QuangHoang Can you explain this please.

Comment: Never mind, I missed the older part. Basically, you want to ignore the zeros in column B when calculating cumsum?

Comment: @QuangHoang yes, I want to ignore the values of weight_1 for is_booked = 0

Comment: You’d better take @CodeDifferent ‘s comment and include the expected output :)

Comment: @QuangHoang added the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) + [`Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
df['new_weight']=5000-(df.mask(df['is_B'].eq(0)).groupby('Date_1')['weight_1'].cumsum()).ffill()
print(df)
```

---

```
        Date_1      Date_2  is_B  weight_1  new_weight
0   01/09/2019  02/08/2019     1       254      4746.0
1   01/09/2019  02/08/2019     1       320      4426.0
2   01/09/2019  04/08/2019     1       244      4182.0
3   01/09/2019  04/08/2019     1       247      3935.0
4   01/09/2019  14/08/2019     0       343      3935.0
5   01/09/2019  14/08/2019     1       161      3774.0
6   01/09/2019  14/08/2019     1       386      3388.0
7   01/09/2019  15/08/2019     1       465      2923.0
8   01/09/2019  15/08/2019     1       133      2790.0
9   01/09/2019  15/08/2019     1       310      2480.0
10  01/09/2019  15/08/2019     1       155      2325.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
df['new_weight'] = df.groupby('date_1').apply(lambda grp:
    5000 - grp.weight_1.where(grp.isBooked.eq(1), 0).cumsum()).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you only need a simple multiplication before groupby:

```
df['new_weight'] = 5000 - (df['weight_1'].mul(df['is_B'])
     .groupby(df['Date_1'])
     .cumsum()
)
```

Output:

```
        Date_1      Date_2  is_B  weight_1  new_weight
0   01/09/2019  02/08/2019     1       254        4746
1   01/09/2019  02/08/2019     1       320        4426
2   01/09/2019  04/08/2019     1       244        4182
3   01/09/2019  04/08/2019     1       247        3935
4   01/09/2019  14/08/2019     0       343        3935
5   01/09/2019  14/08/2019     1       161        3774
6   01/09/2019  14/08/2019     1       386        3388
7   01/09/2019  15/08/2019     1       465        2923
8   01/09/2019  15/08/2019     1       133        2790
9   01/09/2019  15/08/2019     1       310        2480
10  01/09/2019  15/08/2019     1       155        2325
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the desired values in the new column ("New_weight"):

```
df.loc[df.is_B == 0, 'new_weight'] = df['weight_1']
df.loc[df.is_B == 1, 'new_weight'] = 5000 - df.groupby('Date_1')['weight_1'].cumsum()
```

Not sure if this answers the "if is_B = 0 then we copy the older value of new_weight into new_weight."